# Azure Devops Stage Is Skipped

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Azure Devops multi stage pipeline in YAML. It looks like so :

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main
    - release/*
    - development

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  isPullRequest: $[eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')]
  isDevelopment: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')]
  releaseDevelopment: $[or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development'),eq(variables.forceRelease, 'true'))]

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
    - job: Build
      steps:
      - powershell: Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=datedFolderName;isOutput=true]$(Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd)"
        name: OutputDatedFolderName

      - task: NodeTool@0
        inputs:
          versionSpec: '16.x'
        displayName: 'Install Node.js'
        
        [... MANY other tasks as part of build]

  - stage: Development
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.releaseDevelopment, true))
    dependsOn:
    - Build
    variables:
      datedFolderName: $[stageDependencies.Build.Build.outputs['OutputDatedFolderName.datedFolderName']]
    jobs:
    - template: 'ado-release.yml'
      parameters:
        environment: 'Development'

  - stage: Test
    condition: succeeded()
    dependsOn:
    - Build
    - Development
    variables:
      datedFolderName: $[stageDependencies.Build.Build.outputs['OutputDatedFolderName.datedFolderName']]
    jobs:
    - template: 'ado-release.yml'
      parameters:
        environment: 'Test'

  - stage: UAT
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.releaseDevelopment, true))
    dependsOn:
    - Build
    - Test
    variables:
      datedFolderName: $[stageDependencies.Build.Build.outputs['OutputDatedFolderName.datedFolderName']]
    jobs:
    - template: 'ado-release.yml'
      parameters:
        environment: 'UAT'
```

Note that ado-release.yml is so we can have one set of release instructions that are the same between environments.

I noticed that if I leave the build to run, on the development branch, it will skip Test.

[image]

Note that the "Check" is an approval by a person. This is based on Environments. However I never get the chance to approve this build, it just bails.

If I retry the stage, then it will go out successfully. But interestingly after Test, it is more than happy to deploy to UAT :

[image]

Any help on why specifically this environment is skipped?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my particular issue. I have it set up that an approver must approve the push into Test. This approval process is set to time out after 30 minutes. Beyond this 30 minutes it simply "skips" the stage.